# Python from PHP in IIS server [WinError -2147024891] Access is denied

Tags: php, iis-8

i try to run Python script using PHP in IIS win 8.1 to convert Docx File into PDF

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client
import random
import string
import qrcode
import fitz
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import json
import base64
import getpass

errordata=0
_output=[]

# convert Docx file into pdf file
def word_to_pdf(_in):
    global errordata
    pdf_format_key = 17

    try:
        file_in = os.path.abspath(_in)
        head =os.path.split(_in)
        _out=str((head[0]+'\\'+os.path.splitext(head[1])[0]+'.pdf'))
        file_out = os.path.abspath(_out)

        worddoc = comtypes.client.CreateObject('word.application')
        doc = worddoc.Documents.open(file_in)
        print ("documnt open")
        doc.SaveAs(file_out,FileFormat=pdf_format_key)

        errordata=0
        _output.append('convert to PDF Success')
    except Exception as e:
        errordata=1
        _output.append('convert to PDF Error' + str(e))

    finally:    
        print(_output)
        if errordata==0:
            randid='_'+ id_generator(30, string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
            qr_generator(randid,_out)


word_to_pdf(sys.argv[1])
```

this is how i call python from PHP :

```
<?php
$result = shell_exec('C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PyTest\document_control.py C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PyTest\upload\testdoc.docx 2>&1');
echo($result);
?>
```

when i run the PHP it fired Error :`[WinError -2147024891] Access is denied']`

i run the script from cmd Administrator and cmd user the script run as i expected

i try to give everyone to read/write permission to upload folder, but the error still persists

please guys hel me out

Comment: And how is this a Python question ? You'd have the same problem with perl or ruby or node or whatever. Fix your IIS config to give it proper permissions.

Comment: I try to creare file using only php and wi no error accure..i know its about iis config but i just dont know how to give right configuraton..would you please help me sir

Comment: Of course no error occurs if you don't try to call shell_exec on executables IIS has no permissions on. This doesn't make it more of a Python question. And sorry but stackoverflow is about programming, not about IIS config.

Comment: Its ok if you dont know how to configure it to sir, hope some body else can help me..thanks anyway sir

Comment: It's not a question of whether I do or not know how to configure IIS, but whether your question is on topic here. I'd say the same thing (and already did) if it was about Apache or nginx.

Comment: Have you tried to set application pool identity to local system because PHP cgi is activated under application pool identity. If the service account don't have enough permission, then the operation will fail. If set local system did the trick, then you can change application pool identity back and use process monitor to find required permission. So that you would who and what permission are required.

Comment: Hi Jokies, i finally find soution for my error here is the link : https://www.itdroplets.com/iis-php-and-windows-authentication-run-as-a-service-account/ in case somebody has same error as me